# How to workaround gcc-3.4 bug (or maybe this is not a bug)?

Tags: c++, gcc

Following code fails with a error message :

```
t.cpp: In function `void test()':
t.cpp:35: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
t.cpp:35: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Now I don't see any issues with the code and it compiles with gcc-4.x and MSVC 2005 but not with gcc-3.4 (which is still quite popular on some platforms).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct message {
        message(std::string s) : s_(s) {}
        template<typename CharType>
        std::basic_string<CharType> str()
        {
                return std::basic_string<CharType>(s_.begin(),s_.end());
        }
private:
        std::string s_;
};


inline message translate(std::string const &s)
{
        return message(s);
}


template<typename TheChar>
void test()
{
        std::string s="text";
        std::basic_string<TheChar> t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;

        t1=translate(s).str<TheChar>(); // ok

        char const *tmp=s.c_str();
        t2=translate(tmp).str<TheChar>(); // ok

        t3=message(s.c_str()).str<TheChar>(); // ok

        t4=translate(s.c_str()).str<TheChar>(); // fails

        t5=translate(s.c_str()).template str<TheChar>(); // ok

        std::cout << t1 <<" " << t2 <<" " << t3 << " " << t4 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        test<char>();
}
```

Is it possible to workaround it on the level of `translate` function and `message` class, or maybe my code is wrong, if so where?

**Edit:**

[Bugs related to template-functions in GCC 3.4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013129/bugs-related-to-template-functions-in-gcc-3-4-6) says I need to use keyword `template` but should I?

Is this a bug? Do I have to write a `template` keyword? Because in all other cases I do not have to? And it is quite wired I do not have to write it when I use ".c_str()" member function.

**Why gcc-4 not always an option**

This program does not starts when compiled with gcc-4 under Cygwin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

class bar : public std::locale::facet  {
public:
        bar(size_t refs=0) : std::locale::facet(refs)
        {
        }
        static std::locale::id id;
};

std::locale::id bar::id;


using namespace std;

int main()
{
        std::locale l=std::locale(std::locale(),new bar());
        std::cout << has_facet<bar>(l) << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

And this code does not compiles with gcc-4.3 under OpenSolaris 2009- broken concepts checks...

```
#include <map>
struct tree {
   std::map<int,tree> left,right;
};
```

Comment: If your compiler requires the keyword `template` in this case, then *it is a bug* in the compiler. The return type of `translate` function is not dependent on any template parameters. The keyword `template` is not required here. Your code is fine in its original form.

Comment: `template` here is required because `str` is a template method.

Comment: So can anybody tell if this is a bug of feature?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better long term to just upgrade GCC? You will also gain better optimized code.

Comment: The issue that gcc-3.4 is only option on some platforms: Cygwin, OpenSolaris.

Comment: @Matthier M.: `str()` is a template method from a non-dependent type. The result of `translate` is a `message` that is not dependent on the type of the template parameter. As such the compiler can know that the `str()` method is templated without the code expliciting it.

Comment: Artyom: As a correction, gcc-3.4 is not the only option on Cygwin.  You just need to explicitly install the "gcc4" package rather than the "gcc" package.

Comment: @Brooks the problem that gcc-4.3 is quite broken under Cygwin. Some compilations that use for example `std::locale` classes just do not start with some wired dll issue. gcc-4.3 is broken on OpenSolaris as well, it fails to compile some basic things.

Comment: Oh, hmm.  I wasn't aware of those bugs.  Do you have a link where I could learn more?

Comment: @Matthieu M: Incorrect. Just because some method is a template method, does not mean that you have to specify `template` every time you call it. The extra `template` required only when the type for which the template method is called is a *dependent* type, i.e. the compiler requires a little help from you, because it won't know in advance that it is a member template. But in this specific case the type is not dependent. The `template` is not required.

Comment: @Artyom: It is a bug. The 3.4 was a rather "notorious" version of GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere, that seems to be a compiler bug.  Fair enough; those exist.  Here's what you do about those:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ < 4
// Use erroneous syntax hack to work around a compiler bug.
t4=translate(s.c_str()).template str<TheChar>();
#else
t4=translate(s.c_str()).str<TheChar>();
#endif
```

GCC always defines `__GNUC__` to the major compiler version number.  If you need it, you also get `__GNUC_MINOR__` and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` for the y and z of the x.y.z version number.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the old compiler. Newer GCC's, from 4.0 to (the yet unreleased) 4.5, accept it, as they should. It is standard C++. (Intel and Comeau accept it also.)

Regarding cygwin and opensolaris, of course gcc-3.4 is not the only option: the newer versions (the released 4.4.3, or the unreleased 4.5 branch) work fine on these OS'es. For cygwin, it's part of the official distribution (see the `gcc4*` packages [in the list](http://cygwin.com/packages/)). For opensolaris, you can compile it yourself (and instructions on how to do so can easily be found with Google).

Comment: True -- though, for a program distributed to other users, "you'll need to compile a compiler in order to build it" does not appeal so much....

Comment: See my examples where gcc-4.3 is broken. gcc-4.x is not always an option.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use a different workaround, since adding the `template` disambiguator there is incorrect and will break if you move to a different compiler later on.

I don't know the real code, but passing a regular `std::string` seems to work (option 1: avoid converting to `const char *` just to create a temporary) or you could provide an overloaded `translate` that takes a `const char*` as argument (if the compiler does not complain there), depending on your requirements.